# error when I concatenate two strings in an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot use concatenation when declaring default class properties in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847905/cannot-use-concatenation-when-declaring-default-class-properties-in-php)

The following code:

```
public $Options = array (0  => 'aaaaa' . 'bbbbb');
```

gives the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
```

I would have expected it simply to give 0 the value of aaaaabbbbb

This is with PHP5. Am I missing something, I'm sure I have used this many time in the past.

Thanks for any help

Comment: tried $Options = array (0  => 'aaaaa'.'bbbbb');
 print_r($Options); and it works fine in php 5.3.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're doing this as part of the class property's declaration which isn't possible due to the fact that:

> ...declaration may include an
>   initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be
>   evaluated at compile time and must not
>   depend on run-time information in
>   order to be evaluated.

See the [PHP manual properties page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) for more information.

However, you could set this property as required within your constructor and all will be well:

```
class TestClass {
    public $Options;

    function __construct() {
        $this->Options = array (0  => 'aaaaa' . 'bbbbb');
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code and it's now working fine. The strange thing is I have some code where an array is defined in the classes property declaration. It's Running on a different server so maybe a different PHP version?

Comment: @jimmy If the array can be constructed at compile time, then it would presumably be fine. That said, concatenation clearly can't be carried out at compile time, hence the problem you had.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating strings in a class' property definition is [invalid in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). You'll need to do it in the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I tested your code. It works here.
Have you tried brackets?

```
public $Options = array (0  => ('aaaaa' . 'bbbbb'));
```

Comment: Since you can also declare it in the classes dec. I assume it must have something to do with the PHP version on the server?

Comment: I guess it's PHP version dependent - it did not work for me on PHP 5.5.38 but it works fine on PHP 5.6.38