# Concatenation in class property

Tags: php, class, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot use concatenation when declaring default class properties in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847905/cannot-use-concatenation-when-declaring-default-class-properties-in-php)

```
class Db extends PDO {
            protected $dsn = "mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DB;
}
```

The above code is not working if i concatenate the string in the class variable. 
How to fix this.

Comment: When you declare the properties of a class, and specify the initial value, you cannot do any operations (like concatenation). Do it in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 5):

PHP doesn't do such operations at compile-time; you cannot assign calculated values to cons    tants, even if all operators are constants themselves.

"Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated."**
---[php.net documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
// invalid property declarations:
public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
public $var2 = <<<EOD
hello world
EOD;
 public $var3 = 1+2;
 public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
 public $var5 = $myVar;

// valid property declarations:
public $var6 = myConstant;
public $var7 = array(true, false);

// This is allowed only in PHP 5.3.0 and later.
public $var8 = <<<'EOD'
hello world
EOD;
}
?>
```

**What you can do is move the initialization to constructor instead..**

Answer (score 1):

Move the initialization in the constructor:

```
class Db extends PDO { 
    protected $dsn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dsn = "mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DB; 
        parent::__construct($this->dsn);
    }
}
```

Of course you will need to actually call the parent constructor with the proper arguments it requires.

Answer (score 0):

Override your derived DB class constructor to initialize PDO with your DSN:

```
class DB extends PDO {

  public function __construct() {

    // Optional, but cool way to initialize client encoding
    $options = array(self::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES "utf8"');

    parent::__construct('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DB, $options);
  }

}

// Usage
$db = new DB();
```